# you do not have the Rights to Modify this application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play

i am trying to upload an App to the play store, but it gives me " you do not have the Rights to Modify this application" What is that and how i can fix it ?

Comment: Is it an update? You probably used another keystore to generate the apk file. You need to use the same to release another version.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are trying to update your own application with a new version, you *must* sign your application with the same keystore file each time. If you lost the password for your keystore... you're out of luck, and may have to release your update as a new application.
- If you are simply trying to upload an application for the first time, this error would show up if the package name of your application is already being used by someone else, as the package name is used as the unique identifier for each application. You can check this by going to the following url:

  `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.full.package.name.here`

  To fix this, simply change the package name of your application.